# How to update all machines in an instance group on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

I have multiple machines managed by auto scaling in Google Compute Engine. I would like to redeploy all my machines (create new ones based on the same instance template and delete all the old ones). I do not want any service interruption.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Rolling updates seems to be a nice solution:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/manager/#applying_rolling_updates_using_the_updater_service

Comment: Rolling updates has now been in Alpha for over 2 years. I requested to use the feature 2 days ago and no one has got back to me. Are there any alternatives that do not bring the site down? The other up-voted answer looks like it will disrupt service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/recreate-instances) to recreate the existing VMs using the new or the same template whichever is set to your managed group:

```
$ gcloud compute instance-groups managed recreate-instances NAME --instances=INSTANCE
```

Comment: During recreation, won't there be a service disruption? Is the recreate algo smart enough to do this so that there is at least one instance to serve requests? Also, when an instance is brought down to be recreated, will the load balance in front be notified so that it does not send requests to the node?